# ncal's -H option does not work

Tags: calendar

ncal's -H options states that:

> ```
>  -H yyyy-mm-dd
>          Use yyyy-mm-dd as the current date (for debugging of highlighting).
> ```

However, it does not work on my machine

```
$ ncal -H 1970-01-01
    June 2020         
Su     7 14 21 28   
Mo  1  8 15 22 29   
Tu  2  9 16 23 30   
We  3 10 17 24      
Th  4 11 18 25      
Fr  5 12 19 26      
Sa  6 13 20 27
```

My ncal's version is BSD March 14  2009 on Kubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-H` sets `yy-mm-dd` as the current *day to highlight* within the chosen month. In order for it to have a visible effect, you also need to set the month appropriately as well, ex.

```
$ ncal -d 1970-01 -H 1970-01-01
    January 1970      
Su     4 11 18 25   
Mo     5 12 19 26   
Tu     6 13 20 27   
We     7 14 21 28   
Th  1  8 15 22 29   
Fr  2  9 16 23 30
Sa  3 10 17 24 31
```

(I used **bold** to indicate the highlighting here since I don't know how to invert in markdown). From `man ncal`:

> ```
>  -d yyyy-mm
>          Use yyyy-mm as the current date (for debugging of date selec‐
>          tion).
>
>  -H yyyy-mm-dd
>          Use yyyy-mm-dd as the current date (for debugging of highlight‐
>          ing).
> ```